# Network File Share Access Speed

Tags: ms-access, fileshare

Working on an update to a MS Access project that hasn't yet been migrated to something (else...better...that doesn't suck).
It has a front-end/back-end design.
One of the updates is to move it to a new SAN that is in our virtual server environment.  Does anyone know if the file `access/db connection speed` will be better if the back-end is housed at `\\root\sub1\` than at `\\root\sub1\sub2`? Does it make a difference either way ?
I have always heard that you should put it as high in the structure as you can but I cant find any supporting documentation to back it up.

Answer (score 1):

It will have no impact.

But why not just try? It wouldn't take you much more time than writing the question here.

Comment: My tests support your answer.  My post here is mainly to see if there was any documentation that supports a case either way.